# No results for valid search query

Tags: search

This is the name of a file in my SharePoint library: `20221205_2ndFloorLabFeedback.docx`

This search query returns no results: `LabFeedback`

Neither does this: `FloorLabFeedback`

This one does: `2ndFloorLabFeedback`

Does anyone have an idea why the first or second query don't work?

Comment: To improve your search results, you can try using wildcard characters (*) in your search query. For example, searching for `*LabFeedback` or `*FloorLabFeedback` may return the desired results by allowing for partial matches within the file names.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but `*LabFeedback` or `*FloorLabFeedback` don't work either!

Answer (score 1):

Your file name contains **( _ )** (in 20221205_2ndFloorLabFeedback.docx) and SharePoint splits on this when crawl data. So in point of view SharePoint your file name is divided into 20221205 and 2ndFloorLabFeedback to be able to find it.

Once you write your query it does ***startsWith*** 20221205 ***or*** 2ndFloorLabFeedback but **LabFeedback** and **FloorLabFeedback** are considered as as single part of ***2ndFloorLabFeedback*** word.

Try to add some separators between if you would like to find by these words or try an option "Finer Query Tokenization" when configure managed property.

Note, that after this content source should be re crawled or (if SharePoint online) should wait for some time (up to 48 hours) to take effect.

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Suppose my file name was LabFeedback.docx. Currently SharePoint returns no results when I search for "Feedback". Would the "Finer Query Tokenization" be helpful in this case? (In other words, I want "LabFeedback.docx" be returned when I search for "Feedback")

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure for this option in this case. Better to split on _ or other separator. Here is official explanations how search SharePoint works https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference. It uses KQL language to find results. Hope it helps.